# Make entire webpage relative to edges of Banner

Tags: html, css

I am new to webpage design (only a week in). I am building my website and have been trying to mimic the approach that this website took [Desired Format](http://tictocgames.com)

They have their entire website centered and all of their content in that one center piece. I am still learning so I assumed what they used was a `div` and simply made all of the content inside relative to the location.

My attempt at doing this is this:[image: My Website]

I added the borders to my banner and what is supposed to be my "side bar" character to show their positions better. I would like the characters position relative to the far left side of the banner so that it looks "in line" and centered like the website example above.

I am very sure that the way I am doing this is bad or , honestly, incorrect but I am willing to learn and have learned alot!

1. Does anyone know what the website example used? Or the methods they
   used? I would like to look them up and learn those styles.
2. Does anyone know how I can fix my own website issue with having the
   `div` location of the side character relative to the far left border
   of the banner?

---

Here is my HTML/CSS so far

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    /*BACKGROUND IMAGE*/
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-image: url("background5.png");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            padding: 1px;
        }
        div#banner {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .nav-bar {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 1px;
            width: 525px;
        }
        ul#nav-bar li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        ul#nav-bar li a {
            text-decoration: underline;
            padding: 10px 0;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 0 1%;
            background: #25aee4;
            color: black;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            border-left: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        div#sidebar {
            border: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>



<body>
<div id="banner">
    <center>
        <img src="owiFull.png" width="1150" height="170" alt="banner" border="1px">
    </center>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
<center>
    <ul id="nav-bar">
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">Current Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</center>
</div>

<div id= "sideBar">
    <img src="pixelSideBar.png" border="1px">
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate anyone who takes the time to teach and help!

Comment: That's called boxed layout, basically, it's not aligned with the banner, but the whole site is wrapped in a div with a % width, and the content covers the whole width of that container.

Comment: @LordNeo I see! I will learn how to use boxed layouts then! Any particular good order I should learn how to do this? If you would would like to submit that as the answer I will accept. Thank you for the help in teaching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the so called, boxed layout. You wrap all your content in one big container with the width of the box defined, and then you adjust your content width relative to this container.

If you're starting making a website, a good thing is to start learning bootstrap or similar framework, wich will help you to get quickly started with layouts and positioning of the content without too much effort (the grid system is awesome).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    /*BACKGROUND IMAGE*/
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-image: url("background5.png");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            padding: 1px;
        }
        div#banner {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .nav-bar {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 1px;
            width: 525px;
        }
        ul#nav-bar li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        ul#nav-bar li a {
            text-decoration: underline;
            padding: 10px 0;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 0 1%;
            background: #25aee4;
            color: black;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            border-left: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        div#sidebar {
            border: 20px;
        }
        /* Added style for the box */
        .boxed {
            width:80%;
            margin-left:10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>



<body>
<!-- We wrap everything in the box and set the sizes according to this box -->
<div class="boxed">
<div id="banner">
    <center>
        <img src="owiFull.png" width="1150" height="170" alt="banner" border="1px">
    </center>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
<center>
    <ul id="nav-bar">
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">Current Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</center>
</div>

<div id= "sideBar">
    <img src="pixelSideBar.png" border="1px">
</div>
<!-- END OF THE WRAPPER -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder how they got 2 different back grounds for the background and "box background"? Thank you for your help and for putting the comments into my code!

Comment: you use the background property for body and boxed

Answer (score 1):

I found one on the first [Internet search](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) I conducted. Keep in mind its not even a little bit responsive but you are a week in so this is good practice. I would use the aside using html5 for the left container.

```
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px; 
}
</style>
```

```
<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
London<br>
Paris<br>
Tokyo
</div>

<div id="section">
<h1>London</h1>
<p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
<p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
Copyright © W3Schools.com
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I apologize I was searching the best I could but I was unable to locate it like you did because I simply did not know what it was called :/

Comment: No apologies necessary, I have been there. Just keep working hard and you will be rewarded one day. :-)

Comment: Also- do they use boxes inside of the BOX to position other items? thank you!

Comment: You mean divs? Yes, use divs to box in elements aka containers with.absolute positioning and make elements inside relative. Get some practice using relative position, div max-width with width: 100%, float left or right with clear none, and margin 0 auto.You may want to read up on twitter bootstrap  in the future because websites are typically responsive now. Be careful with padding because it has different effects in IE, Also, please click on check mark if this is the answer